# Time difference between two time stamps having format YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ffffff in excel

Tags: excel, timestamp

```
 ExecStartTime               ExecEndTime
 2017-10-18 11:01:06.000000  2017-10-18 11:01:07.000000
 2017-10-18 11:01:34.000000  2017-10-18 11:01:35.000000
 2017-10-18 11:01:36.000000  2017-10-18 11:01:37.000000
 2017-10-18 11:01:38.000000  2017-10-18 11:01:39.000000
 2017-10-18 11:01:40.000000  2017-10-18 11:01:41.000000
 2017-10-18 11:01:43.000000  2017-10-18 11:01:44.000000
```

How can I get the difference between ExecEndTime and ExecStartTime in excel?
I am getting #value as answer.
TIA.

Comment: What formula are you trying?  `A2-A1` worked for me?

Comment: Yeah tried the same , but I am getting #value

Answer (score 0):

Let the two columns be `General` formatting.  In a third column, you can subtract the two, and format the result as `Time`:

[image]

Comment: Still not getting the same @bruce

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your data? Has it been trimmed (no leading/trailing spaces/characters)?

Comment: Even if it's been trimmed, you sometimes need to do something to get Excel to treat it as a numerical or date value instead of a string. If there isn't too much data, the easiest way is to just "edit" the cell without changing the value.